# Congruence relationship used for primitive residue classes modulo n result

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to understand a proof for a theorem that states conditions under which the group of primitive residual classes modulo $n$ is cyclic. This proof uses the following result attributed to Gauß:
$$
(1 + p)^{p^{\nu - 1}} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^\nu},\qquad(1 + p)^{p^{\nu - 1}} \not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^{\nu + 1}},
$$
where $p$ is an odd prime and $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$.

This result is used to derive without further explanation the following incongruence
$$
(1 + p)^{p^{\nu - 2}} \not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^{\nu}}
$$
where $\nu \geq 2$.

Can somebody explain how one can obtain the second incongruence from the first one? It's probably something simple, but I'm just not seeing it at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bottom line is just the first with $\nu$ shifted by one.

Comment: Arrghh, of course. Thanks.